# How to hide columns of subfolders inside a library?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-library

There is a library with folders which has some columns, the folders also have sub-folders in it which are inheriting columns .. any way to hide sub-folder columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in Folder in SP Library. However, you can use Document Sets instead of folders. You can create content types for Document Sets and you can add/edit columns as per your need

Answer (score 8):

Go to advanced settings for the library and check "Per-Location View Settings".

Here you should be able to set that the top in your hierarchy only uses a view that shows the column, and then set another view for all the others sub folders.

[Configure the availability of views for a location in the site hierarchy](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-availability-of-views-for-a-location-in-the-site-hierarchy-7930b539-55af-4b2f-8d6e-4e0cf263193c)

[Per-location view settings don't work at the folder level in SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2010, and SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806007/per-location-view-settings-don-t-work-at-the-folder-level-in-sharepoin)

Comment: Yes i am using SP2013 only. and it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: Is there anything similar in sharepoint online?  All subfolders are inheriting the view from the parent folder.

Comment: @gorav and OP. I am running into the same issue I am not sure if you have solved this or not but in 2013 SP, I am pretty sure all you have to do is use a document set instead of a folder